# html, php con conexión a mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Al momento de entrar con el usuario admin me manda error en la contraseña, ya he intentado de 2 formas y me sigue saliendo lo mismo, que el error es en la contraseña.

```
<?php

$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
$mysqli= new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "valorantwiki");

$sql="SELECT * FROM `usuario` WHERE `usuario`='$usuario'  ";
$resultado=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
$num=$resultado->num_rows;
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

if($row['id_cargo']==1){ //administrador
    header("location:neon.html");

}else
    if($row['id_cargo']==2){ //cliente
    header("location:raze.html");
}
    else{
    ?>   
    <?php
    include("login.php");
    ?> 
    //<h1 class="bad">ERROR EN LA AUTENTIFICACION</h1>
    <?php
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Answer (score 2):

Estuve viendo tu código y como no tenemos el código de tu html, asumo que no tienes problemas con el, pero en todo caso deberías incluir una rutina de comprobación de la conexión para descartar que realmente tu problema no esta ahí mediante:

```php
/* comprobar la conexión */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

Hay una variable $num la cual no logre entender cual es su objetivo, por lo tanto la descarté. Y por último tu selección se ve mas clara con un switch, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```php
<?php
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

session_start();
$_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;

$mysqli= new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "valorantwiki");

/* comprobar la conexión */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM `usuario` WHERE `usuario`='$usuario'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);  

if ($resultado) {
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
       $opt = $row['id_cargo'];
       switch ($opt) {
        case 1: //Administrador
                header("location:neon.html");
                break;
        case 2: //Cliente
                header("location:raze.html");
                break;
        default:
            echo '<h1 class="bad">ERROR EN LA AUTENTIFICACION</h1>';   
       }
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```